# How to deploy angular 2 project?

Tags: angular

How can I deploy **angular 2 service**?
Its the first time for doing an angular 2 application.

Anyone can help?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Basically you just need to copy your application to a non local web server. You can sign up for free at https://www.heroku.com/
Other than that I would encourage you to read the angular documentation that describes deployment in great detail here: https://angular.io/guide/deployment

Answer (score 0):

First, you tagged this as `angularjs` which is the wrong tag (that's for the angular 1.x versions).  But angular2 deployment is super easy with the [angular cli](https://cli.angular.io/).

You'll need to have created the project with the cli, not sure if it's a headache to add it in after the fact.  And then you just do `ng-build --prod` which will build your `dist` folder.  You take that and put it on your deployment server, whatever that is.  Could be apache or nginx or whatever.